# What word would you use for "Artificial Intelligence and Humans"?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, word-request, phrase-request

My first guess was "Creatures" (I'm not a native speaker), but I have a strange feeling about this word. I also checked "Entities" but for me, it has a mystical meaning that is hidden in the word. 
What is your suggestion?

A sample sentence

*As much as it can, Artificial Intelligence should ensure that it is at peace with every **Creatures** it relates with, and Artificial Intelligence should also try to bring peace to its own environment and society.*

Candidates

- "Intelligent Beings"
- "Self Perceiving Beings"
- "Self Aware Beings"
- "Complex Aware Beings"

Comment: Perhaps **agents** but more context is needed. **Creatures** usually refers to fauna.

Comment: You are asking whether both Artificial Intelligence and Humans are some kind of X, where X would be "Creatures", "Entities", or some other words, right?

Answer (score 2):

Creatures doesn't work at all. This includes animals, but excludes man (and robots)

Entities is very broad.  It means the same as "Things".

You can say "intelligent beings" or some similar expression ("sentient", "self aware", "Self Perceiving"). Or even a new acronym "IBs".  Since this is science fiction (no general artificial intelligence exists.) you can invent a new term for "what future people might say".  Of course you need to subtlely show people what the new or changed words mean in the story. Usually you do this by using the new words with enough context for readers to understand.  But now this is writing.se not ELL.

For example it might be that in the future it is considered rude to discriminate between human and artificial intelligence, so the term "people" is used for both.

> There were five people on the starship. Two human and three AIs, one of whom, Katy, was embodied.
>
> As much as they can, artificial intelligences should ensure that they are at peace with every person they relate with (whether artificial or biological), and artificial intelligences should also try to bring peace to their own environment and society.

Comment: I like the idea of a new term and you are right it would be a fiction.
Using an already existing term like "people" won't work just like in case of "sports" and "esports". The majority won't understand the point here, that you use "people" because you would like to avoid discrimination and you would like to emphasize the respect towards them.

Comment: Maybe "Self Perceiving Beings".

Comment: At this point I think it becomes a matter for "writing.se".  If you do your worldbuilding right you can establish the new words and their nuances. Like I tried to do in the example, I establish that "people" means something different to usual. Part of most Sci-fi writing is subtlely showing people what the world you have built is like, and showing that "people" includes AI because we avoid discrimination...

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely consider using "sentient beings" or "sentient life".

This word ([sentience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentience)) describes something that is able to experience things and feel emotion. This word is commonly used in science fiction. Note that animal sentience is still somewhat debated, so some readers may assume that the the word "sentient" only applies to intelligent life (like humans and AI) and some will assume that it applies to all living creatures with brains.

**Sentient beings** includes sentient artificial intelligence and all other sentient things.

**Sentient life** specifically refers to living things that are sentient.